# Had to rename pcmcia.sys to get Win7 to work... Now what?

Tags: windows-7

Older laptop which had xp. Did a clean install of 7 which went well until first boot where it would just sit. After much searching and trying of things I finally found the suggestion that I use the command prompt to rename pcmcia.sys to pcmcia.bak

After reboot I got right in.... But without my wireless card or sound or other pcmcia things.... Which is obviously untenable.

I tried using the install disc to get to command prompt and renaming it back but, surprise, it would once again just hang on the boot screen.

In all my years I've never once had to mess with anything like this so I really have no idea what to do now.

It's an older (2005ish) toshiba laptop. Is there a way to generate a new pcmcia file that will work ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't simply generate a new `pcmcia.sys` file somehow, because that's the generic PCMCIA driver bundled with Windows 7. Being a 2005 model it was built before the release of even Windows Vista, and chances are it might not be able to run anything newer than XP. If still want to use Windows 7 (or at least try to), you should specify: 1. the laptop exact model, 2. the technical specifications, and 3. the installed devices and their hardware IDs.

Comment: Have you checked the manufacturer's website to see if the unit is even compatible with Windows 7? If it's not, you could be wasting your time. If it is, there may be updated drivers available for download.

Comment: Okay I will update with those specs when I get home this evening. --Question in the meantime - win7 upgrade advisor passed me for being able to upgrade (does that matter?) Also, lets say I find some new drivers what will the process be? Can I update drivers without a pcmcia.sys file? I can't get into my working system with that file live... Thanks!